# pre-pend to each element in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-structures, jruby

Is there a way to prepend each element of an array with something.

eg:

```
file = File.new(my_file,'r')

header = IO.readlines(my_file)[1]  # header looks like [1,2,3]
#Prepend each elelement of header with filename, something like
header.prepend(filename+".")     #header looks like [filename.1,filename.2,filename.3]
```

Answer (score 19):

You want to use map:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"].map { |word| "prepend-#{word}" }
#=> ["prepend-foo", "prepend-bar", "prepend-baz"]
```

classic case for this method.  This method can also take an array containing elements of any type.

Comment: Uh, you're right. I should have tested my code in a console first - map is the correct way to do this. +1

Answer (score 1):

We have a default method for prepending elements to an array.

```
header = [1, 2, 3]

header.map { |h| h.to_s.prepend("filename.")}}
```

Output:

```
["filename.1", "filename.2", "filename.3"]
```